# What is the easiest way to get a crash stack trace from Android?

Tags: android

Many of my beta testers are non-developers and don't know how to use Eclipse. Is there an EASY way for non-techies to send me stack traces after a crash?

Is Eclipse the only way to see a stack trace for an Android app?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrate [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) into your app. All crashes (unhandled exceptions) will be posted to a Google Spreadsheet (or a web app you provide) and you can get realtime notifications by email. If you add the required permission, it can also collect logcat automatically.

[Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com) does something similar with a much nicer interface, but report
 details are somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks! Bugsense can read ACRA crash reports so I've set it up that way and hopefully I'll get the best of both.

Comment: When used with ACRA, Bugsense shows only a subset of the information ACRA sends. But if you only need the stacktrace, that might be sufficient.