# set property to web service failed

Tags: java, android, web-services, debugging

I'm trying to set property in my web service but it returns null pointer exception. I tried to hard code in my web service and it working fine. The problem occur when i try to set the property. Please help.

First I tried this:

```
String tagid ="AB6614CD";           
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("tagid");
pi.setValue(tagid);
pi.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty("tagid",tagid);
```

Second I tried this:

```
String tagid ="AB6614CD";  
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();   
request.addProperty("arg0", tagid);
```

Both way failed. Please help thanks.
Below is the trace.
[image]

Comment: A stack trace for the NullPointerException would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: Using PropertyInfo for web service properties sounds odd, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ fdierre im testing from my mobile, no idea how i can get the trace..
@ Joachim Isaksson my web service is fetching data based on the parameter that im passing. I use propertyinfo to pass my parameter to webservice.

Comment: @chinna_82 have you tried looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599540/how-to-view-the-error-stack-trace-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142590/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-crash-stack-trace-from-android ?

Comment: @fdierre if not mistaken both are for eclipse.. Im testing the app from my mobile

Comment: @chinna_82 when you use Eclipse to automatically deploy and start the application on your Android, you also get to see the device's logs (and many other nice things) if you keep it connected to the pc with your usb cable.

Comment: @fdierre my mobile is connected via USB but its connected with my eclipse(android project). Each time i need to export the project into my local, move the .avk into my mobile, install there and test.

Comment: @chinna_82 that's not the recommended workflow: you should first learn how to run the application on the device while running the debugger on your pc with eclipse, and have the two connected.

Comment: @fdierre please find the trace above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine now, after minor fix.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://sposter.smartag.my")]
```

I removed "/" at the end of namespace. Strange, but anyhow it fixed my issue.